# PHP - U+FFFD Unicode � error instead of the char

Tags: php, utf-8, char, non-ascii-characters, htmlspecialchars

I have tested my website on localhost but once uploaded i see that in the
address is not displayed correctly. The address contains the following errror:

```
 37 Gr�ce Ave
```

instead of

```
37 Grâce Ave,
```

Here there is the beginning of my html page:

```html
<html lang="en-ca">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
```

On localhost the address `$address='37 Grâce Ave,'` is displayed correctly.
I have a lot of addresses with these special chars, how can i fix this error?

Comment: Please read ["Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552) as well as [ask] and [edit] your post.

Comment: @Nick, ok  done!

Comment: @daniele add the output of `var_dump(bin2hex($address));` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Save your php file using UTF-8 encoding again, or change the charset to latin-1 (or the one you are currently using) in the head.

To convert a string from one encoding to UTF-8, you can use functions like [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

```
$address = iconv('encoding-of-the-column', 'utf-8', $address);
```

Explanation: Your current file (or the string) should have been saved using one of the european encoding, the value of `â` is greater than 0x7F, in UTF-8 encoding a single character greater than 0x7F is invalid, so it's displayed as an error character.

Comment: the value of the address is not static but it is stored in mysql for each field. How can i solve saving my php file using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: latin-1 is an educated guess right? until i see the bin2hex($address), i'm not sure what charset OP is using, but it's a charset issue yes

Comment: @daniele You need to first know what encoding is used in the DB, then you can use functions like iconv or mb_convert_encoding to convert it.

Comment: @hanshenrik Yes, it's a guess, based on `lang="en-ca"`, it is most likely.